# Refresh a JTable after insert data in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jpanel

i´ve been trying to refresh de JTable after inserting data in MySql, but i cant manage to make it work.

The data is filled in the agregar JPanel and saved after clicking a button, checking in the mysql console, the data is added to the database, but when i open the table it doesn´t update unless i restart the program.

This is My code:

```
public class verTodos extends JPanel {

    contactoDAO dao = new contactoDAO();
    List<contacto> contactos = dao.getAll();
    private JTable table;

    public verTodos() {         
             String[] colName = { "Id", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Telefono",
                "Direccion", "Email", "Rubro1", "Rubro2", "Rubro3" };
         Object[][] obj = new Object[contactos.size()][10];         
         for (int i = 0; i < contactos.size(); i++) {
            contacto c = contactos.get(i);     
            obj[i][0] = c.getId();
            bj[i][1] = c.getNombre();
            obj[i][2] = c.getApellido();
            obj[i][3] = c.getTelefono();
            obj[i][4] = c.getDireccion();
            obj[i][5] = c.getEmail();
            obj[i][6] = c.getRubro1();
            obj[i][7] = c.getRubro2();
            obj[i][8] = c.getRubro3();    
            setBounds(100, 100, 800, 300);                          
        }
        DefaultTableModel contactTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(obj,colName);           
        table = new JTable(contactTableModel);          
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));    
        contactTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
        contactTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colName);            
            add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        repaint();    
    }    
}
```

this is the main screen that contains the JPanels:

```
public class principal extends JFrame {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel container = new JPanel();
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
private final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

/.....
.....

private final JMenuItem mntmVerTodos = new JMenuItem("Ver todos");
    private final JMenuItem mntmAgregar = new JMenuItem("Agregar");
agregar ag = new agregar();
verTodos ver = new verTodos();
...
    ...


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new principal();

        }
    });

}


public principal() {

    textField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
    textField.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 0));
    textField.setColumns(10);

    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int X = (screen.width / 2) - (1366 / 2);
    int Y = (screen.height / 2) - (720 / 2);

    frame.setBounds(X, Y, 1363, 720);

    container.setLayout(cl);
    ver.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    container.add(ver, "ver");
            container.add(ag, "ag");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

    frame.getContentPane().add(container);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);
            cl.show(container, "ver");

    mntmVerTodos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            cl.show(container, "ver");


        }
    });

    mnContactos.add(mntmVerTodos);





    mnContactos.add(mntmAgregar);
    mntmModificar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cl.show(container, "mod");

        }
    });



    menuBar.add(btn);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repopulate your model once the database has been updated. Add a refresh button that when clicked, updates contactTableModel

Comment: i want it to refresh automatically when data is added to the database, which are added in another JPanel, so when i come back to the verTodos JPanel, it´s already updated. As i´ve been watching i realized the problem is that the JPanel doesn´t refresh when i come back to it

Comment: If you want it to refresh automatically, you could create a thread that monitors the database and looks for for if there is any changes and if so, update the table. If you upload the full project somewhere, I could further help.

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly, i´ve just edited the post with the container of the panels, is there any way to make the verTodos panel reload when i click the JmenuItem mntmVerTodos?